# Prevent refresh webview in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm creating an app that loads my website to a webview. I want to prevent that page reloads when I came back to app. If I change to other app or power off and came back the page shows without refresh, the problem occurs only it stays off for a few minutes. I think that the application change the state to stop or is destroyed and when I enter again is called the method oncreate.

I've tried to change android:launchMode to singleTop an singleTask without success, is the creation of a service the solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In order to prevent refreshing of `WebView`, you need to save and restore state.

This is done by overriding lifecycle methods `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState`

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outBundle)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outBundle);
    webView.saveState(outBundle);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedBundle)
{
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedBundle);
    webView.restoreState(savedBundle);
}
```

Furthermore, you can try to set cache on the `WebView` instance.

```
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I continue with the same problem, I will try to use a foreground-service.

Comment: Works with a foreground-service but I give up that idea because the annoing notification. Now I'm using JobScheduler based in [this article](https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/jobscheduler)